# Read excel row into array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have code to read excel file in PHP.
I can display all rows, but I need to put it to array in specific (for me) way.

My data is:

```
row1: 1, model1a, 2, 124
row2: 2, model2,  1, 63
row3: 1, model1b, 1, 525
row4: 1, model1c, 4, 1100
```

row[0] - it is column 0 of given row

row[1] - column 1 of his row, etc.

I want to create array in this way (pseudocode):

```
$payment_data = array();

for(row : rows){
  if( !isset( $payment_data[row[0]] )){
      // there is no array for key row[0], i.e. for row1 $payment_data[1], so create it
      $payment_data[row[0]] = array('income' => array(), 'model' => array(), 'amount' => array() );

     // set values in this array
    $payment_data[row[0]]['income'][0] =  row[1];
    $payment_data[row[0]]['amount'][0] =  row[2];
    $payment_data[row[0]]['model'][0] =  row[3];
}else{
    // array already created and have one value

    // WHAT SHOULD BE HERE FOR ROW3 AND ROW4, SO INDEX IS AGAIN 1 AND ARRAY ALREADY EXISTS
}
```

What should be in ELSE statement to add next elements to array for given key?

For this example the result should be like:

$payment_data has 2 elements with index 1 (from row1, row3 and row4) and 2 (from row 2).
$payment_data[1] should have 3 antries:

```
$payment_data[1]: 
income[0] = 124;
model[0] = model1a;
amount[0] = 2;

income[1] = 525;
model[1] = model1b;
amount[1] = 1;

income[2] = 1100;
model[2] = model1c;
amount[2] = 4;


$payment_data[2]: 
income[0] = 63;
model[0] = model2;
amount[0] = 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution:

```
$payment_data = array();

for(row : rows){
  if( !isset( $payment_data[row[0]] )){
      // there is no array for key row[0], i.e. for row1 $payment_data[1], so create it
      $payment_data[row[0]] = array('income' => array(), 'model' => array(), 'amount' => array() );     
   }
   // set values in this array
    $payment_data[row[0]]['income'][] =  row[1];
    $payment_data[row[0]]['amount'][] =  row[2];
    $payment_data[row[0]]['model'][] =  row[3];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [explode function](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.explode.php) on "," to get separately the 4 values in an array.

Comment: It is not a case. I dont know what should be in ELSE statement, to add next element to the array.